# Mongoose always return empty array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Im new to nodejs.i already have a db named aqi with collection name pln. Im trying to show all the records in collection on web page but mongoose always returns empty array.
i have tested it with other dbs but i can get data from them but for pln mongoose always return empty array.
i would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.
this is my schema

```
var Pln = new Schema({
    latit      : Number,
    longit     : Number,
    timestmp   : String,
    co         : Number,
    smoke      : Number,
    O3         : Number,
    humidity   : Number,
    temperature: Number,
    co2        : Number,
    dust       : String
});
var plnModel = mongoose.model('pln', Pln);
```

This is my route.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.contentType('application/json'); 
    plnModel.find({}, function(err, pln) {
        if (pln != null) {
            console.log('Found the User:' + pln.latit);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(pln));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you know it returns an empty array? You're not logging it. `pln` in an array, so testing for `if (pln != null)` is useless as this will always be true. On the other hand, `pln.latit` will always be undefined because `[].latit` is undefined. Also, why are you stringifying the documents? It can't work, because you set `contentType('application/json')` and you're sending back a string. Just send back `res.status(200).json(pln)`.

Comment: I did log it and in console it also returns []. But i have tested it with my test database i can see all the data.

Comment: what is your DB name? how many records does it have?

Comment: db name is aqi and collection name is pln with about 1610 records

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you define your model this way : `mongoose.model('pln', Pln)`, then your collection *must* be named `'plns'` (= your model name + s )

If that's not the case, then you have to tell Mongoose that you have a custom collection name (in your case, from your comments, `'pln'` without a s) by using :

`mongoose.model('pln', Pln, 'pln')`, the third argument being your collection's actual name.

And have a look at this code :

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        const pln = await plnModel.find().lean().exec(); // "lean" to get only JSON data (not Mongoose objects), faster
        console.log('Found Users :', pln);
        res.status(200).json(pln);
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much man... your'e a life saver.. worked perfectly .

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for your answer and for getting straight to the point. I found 2 other answers to this question that weren't really clicking for me but now I understand what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeremy. You are amazing

Comment: @pdsla112 Haha well thank you ^^